# Setting tags to each item in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a ListView where I want each item to have an ID number attached to it (not the same as the position number). I was hoping this could be done by setting a tag to each View item in the ListView using `setTag()` when these Views are being created.

Right now I'm creating the ListView like this:

```
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `names` variable in the ArrayAdapter parameters above is an ArrayList, and each string value in this list also has a unique ID that I want to link to this string somehow.

Is there any way I can get access to and modify each of the Views with a tag? One idea was to create my own extended class of ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method, but I don't really understand how it works and how I would go about doing this.

Or is there a better way to link IDs with each string like this than adding tags like I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. thisMayhem's answer would probably have been easier in the end, but on my quest to learn more I ended up making my own adapter according to [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/). I pass down the names and the IDs into the adapter and set the names as the text of the TextViews and the IDs as the tags.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `ViewBinder` and set the tags as the `ListView` is being populated with whatever you need. You can check all properties of the view to determine what tag goes where, so this should be what you're looking for.

```
myAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());

public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String text){
        //Since it iterates through all the views of the item, change accordingly 
        if(view instanceof TextView){ 
            ((TextView)view).setTag("whatever you want");
        }
    }
}
```

I just used this exact same answer on another question (albeit slightly different) yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, but `setViewBinder()` doesn't seem to work with Android's ArrayAdapter<String>? Eclipse says the method is undefined for this type. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was using a SimpleAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter I believe

Answer (score 1):

about getView , it works by using a method of recycling views. i will try to explain it in a simple way.

suppose you have tons of items that can be viewed . you don't want to really create tons of views too , since that would take a lot of memory . google thought of it and provide you the means to update only the views that need to be shown at any specific time.

so , if there is an empty space on the listview , it will be filled with a new view . if the user scrolls , the view that becomes hidden is recycled and given back to you on the getView , to be updated with the data of the one that is shown instead .

for example , if you scroll down , the upper view becomes hidden for the end user , but in fact it becomes the exact same view that is on the bottom .

in order to understand how to make the listview have the best performance and see in practice how and why it works as i've talked about , watch this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

as for tags , i think you want to do something else , since the data itself (usually some sort of collection, like an arrayList) already knows where to update , because you get the position via the getView . if you want a specific view to update , you might be able to do so by using a hashmap that keeps upadting , which its key is the position in the collection , and the value is the associated view . on each time you go to getView , you need to remove the entry that belong to the view (if exists) and assign the new position with the view that you got/created .

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with the solution discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668591/1108032). It is always the easiest to have all related data in same place and in this case you just create a class to hold all the information you will need for every item.