# Android ListView - Select element by database table ID

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I have a `listView` which I populate from `contentUri1` using `loader1`/`adapter1`.

What I now need to do is monitor `contentUri2` with `loader2` in order to update the items in the same `listView` with additional data.

So in order to do this, I am wondering if there any way I can select elements from `listView` by their underlying database table ID (as the database table IDs are common for `contentUri1` and `contentUri2`)?

(A workaround I have considered is to create and use a single `contentUri3` that consolidates the data from `contentUri1` and `contentUri2` but I would rather not have to take this approach if avoidable.)

Any other workarounds/suggestions also appreciated.

Comment: You could try setting a tag on each listView item with the database table ID. Then, you could call getTag on them to determine which ones you want selected.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644142/setting-tags-to-each-item-in-a-listview-in-android (?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a Model class that contains the contentUri and the ids. Something like:

```
public class ListContents {

    private Uri contentUri;
    private int id;

    public ListContents(Uri contentUri, int id) {
        this.contentUri = contentUri;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Uri getContentUri() {
        return this.uri:
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

You can then create an `ArrayList` of this class and you will be able to retrieve ids associated with every contentUri. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use an invisible textView to store the value of the id.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashExample = new ArrayList<>();


            Integer id = 1 ;
            String value = "value";

                HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("ID", "" + id);
                map.put("VALUE", value);
                hashExample.add(map);                


            String[] from = {"ID", "VALUE"};
            int[] to = {R.id.txtID, R.id.txtValue};
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), hashExample,
                    R.layout.list_item_example, from, to);
            ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

           list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To retrieve the data, implement this in on onItemClickListener or something

```
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                     Integer id = Integer.valueOf(((Map<String, String>) adapter.getItem(arg2)).get("ID"));

                        String value= ((Map<String, String>) adapter.getItem(arg2)).get("VALUE");

                    }
                });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are populating your `listView` add the tags to the individual items:

```
YourListItemView.setTag(YourTagKey, YourTagValue);
```

Then, when you need it, call `getTag` on the view to retrieve the tag:

```
String tagValue = YourListItemView.getTag(YourTagKey);
```