# How do I add a TextView inside a ListView (or make 2 ListViews into one scrollable one)?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've looked around for solutions but my case seems simpler and I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do it.

My Current ListView:

```
Game 1
Game 2
Game 3
Game 4
```

What I want to get:

```
Game 1
Game 2
------------
Other Games
------------
Game 3
Game 4
```

How I am currently achieving "what I want to get" is by having Game 1 + Game 2 be in ListView #1, then I have a a single TextView of 1dp width that is the `---------` bar followed by a "Other Games" TextView (with a custom gradient background) followed by another 1dp width `---------` bar. followed by Game 3 + Game 4 being in ListView #2. However, this is not desirable as when the games populate, ListView #1 and #2 are scrollable separately and since the list of games are all in one screen, I want the whole screen to be scrollable and not the individual ListViews. How would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: try to use expandable listview

Comment: Use Section Header List View. http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a bit different approach. Simply put everything into one ListView.

When creating ListView adapter you can either use tags [(more about tags here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) and depending on its value ex. when user clicks you do something either you dont do anything. You can even modify colors etc. You can also use more rich objects than just a text as listview item [(more here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668495/android-listview-and-tag).

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand, you simply want to add divider to a current ListView.

See http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/